# Three Tier Application Model Setup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, three-tier

This may be to broad for a direct answer but if I can get some opinions its better then nothing, We are building a three tier application, the data layer (database connection) will consist of wcf services which will be called via the website and external mobile applications.

The project it self will be built within the MVC 5 Environment, now in regards to the MVC models I'm not 100% in to where I should keep these normally in a MVC Application you have the folder "Models", but as I have a three tier application and the application will be calling the data layer to return data from the server and also perform CRUD Operations.

To me it seems right to store the models in the data layer, that way from the web site I'll add a reference to the data layer so I can use the models and pass/retrieve them when I need to would you say this is correct way of doing it?

Comment: Why was I down voted with no explanation?

Answer (score 0):

I have just found this blog, which has explained near enough everything I was looking for, I'll place the modes in the second tier :)

[3 tier web application development](http://weblogs.asp.net/nannettethacker/3-tier-web-application-development)